# Python Iterating Dataframe then output formatting issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, loops, for-loop

This code works to iterate through the data frame and output the needed information but I'm having problems and looking for suggestions on how to correct to the output format needed.  Not concerned so much with the output to excel - just need help with the "reformatting"

Code so far...

```
import pandas as pd

boston = pd.read_excel('e1 Copy.xlsx')

for profile in boston.iterrows():

    print(profile)
```

Given this Dataset

Profile.....Date.........1AM.......2AM......3AM

E1 ...........1/1/1998.....A...........B............C

E1 ...........1/2/1998.....D...........E............F

E1 ...........1/3/1998.....G...........H............I

Produce the following output to an excel file named Output.xlsx

E1.......1/1/1999.......1AM.....A

E1.......1/1/1999.......2AM.....B

E1.......1/1/1999.......3AM.....C

E1.......1/2/1999.......1AM.....D

E1.......1/2/1999.......2AM.....E

E1.......1/2/1999.......3AM.....F

E1.......1/3/1999.......1AM.....G

E1.......1/3/1999.......2AM.....H

E1.......1/3/1999.......3AM.....I

Comment: Why the output date is all `1/1/1999` ?

Comment: Oops - I'll correct

Comment: Corrected!  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If your `df` looks like:

```
  Profile      Date 1AM 2AM 3AM
0      E1  1/1/1998   A   B   C
1      E1  1/2/1998   D   E   F
2      E1  1/3/1998   G   H   I
```

then you can use [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt):

```py
print(df.melt(["Profile", "Date"]).sort_values(by="Date"))
```

Prints:

```
  Profile      Date variable value
0      E1  1/1/1998      1AM     A
3      E1  1/1/1998      2AM     B
6      E1  1/1/1998      3AM     C
1      E1  1/2/1998      1AM     D
4      E1  1/2/1998      2AM     E
7      E1  1/2/1998      3AM     F
2      E1  1/3/1998      1AM     G
5      E1  1/3/1998      2AM     H
8      E1  1/3/1998      3AM     I
```